# RuleBasedCollator not working on Android?

Tags: android, sorting

I try sort string with `RuleBasedCollator` on android. But no one example from https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html  not working and throw exception on android 5.

```
    Caused by: java.text.ParseException: ucol_openRules failed: U_INVALID_FORMAT_ERROR (at offset -1)   
   at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:114)
```

For example, code will throw exception

```
 String simple = "< a< b< c< d";
 RuleBasedCollator mySimple = new RuleBasedCollator(simple);
```

Also I try tips from article http://envyandroid.com/rulebasedcollator-crashes-android-5-0/ but still not working

Comment: the article you quote says "You have to add an initial reset character, which is: & to your rule string." for 5 and up. Did you do that?

Comment: of course rule `"&< a< b< c< d"` also throw exception. I  wrote that the article is not help

Comment: "of course", but that's more obvious if you actually say so. I'd rather not assume anything at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve problem.
On android must be used `"&a< b< c< d"` pattern without first `<` char. On pure java this pattern will throw exception and must be used `"<a<b<c<d"`